# Responsive Fotorama. How to responsive it to middle div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, fotorama

I have added the Fotorama gallery to site, but it's not responsive on mobile devices. I think,  because data-width=100% and it uses width of image or middle div at all.

```
 <div class="wrapper">
...
<div class="middle">
<div class="gallery"><div class="fotorama" data-nav="thumbs" data-arrows="true" data-click="true" data-swipe="true"
     data-width="100%"
     data-ratio="800/600"
     data-maxwidth="889"
     data-maxheight="604"
     data-loop="true">
...
```

and css:

```
#wrapper {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.47);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.47);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.47);
}

.middle {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1% 0 2%;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
}

 .gallery {margin: 1.1% 3% 0 3%;}
```

Web-page: http://lfk-br.com.ua/gallery.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a problem [in your code](http://codepen.io/Leagnus/pen/YqVgBg?editors=1100).

Maybe you just need:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
```

in the head of your page to claim that it has been adapted for mobile devices,

and that they shouldn't use automatic zoom.